# Turning Python short form for loop into long form

Tags: python

I have got this line of code from https://stevenloria.com/tf-idf/

```
scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
```

Where the tfidf function is:

```
import math
from textblob import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
    return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob.words)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)
```

In order to better understand the process, I'd like to turn the shorthand loop into a regular-looking "for" loop.

Would this be correct?

```
scores = []
for word in blob.words:
    scores.append(tfidf(word, blob, bloblist))
```

Also, what's the advantage or writing short-form for loops?

Comment: The original line of code is a dictionary comprehension, not a list comprehension, you can tell by the curly braces and the `key:value` pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this be correct?

That code will give you a list, but your original code produces a dictionary. Instead, try:

```
scores = {}
for word in blob.words:
    scores[word] = tfidf(word, blob, bloblist)
```

> Also, what's the advantage or writing short-form for loops?

The primary advantage of list comprehensions (and dict comprehensions, etc) is that they are shorter than their long-form equivalents.

Comment: Shorter (and faster) according to the link in the comments

Answer (score 1):

These are called [comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (example is for the most common case, list comprehension, although this one is a dictionary comprehension).

They are often simpler and more readable, but if you find them confusing, it's exactly the same to write it out the way you did, with one difference

```
scores = {}
for word in blob.words:
    scores[word] = (tfidf(word, blob, bloblist))
```

Comment: I think the key (word) of the dictionary shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Good point. Fixed.